# Modifying a file that is being used as an output redirection by another program

Tags: linux, terminal

If I have a file of which some output are redirected to, what will happen if I modify that file from another program? Will both changes be recorded to the file?

To illustrate:

Terminal 1 (a file is used to store output of a program using either `tee` or the redirection operator `>`:

```
$ ./program | tee output.log
```

Terminal 2 (at the same time, the log file is being modified by another program, e.g. vim):

```
$ vim output.log
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: From what I've tried, it seems that it would simply append the content to the said file correctly. However I wonder if there are some edge cases where the system would do unexpected things such.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the program and the system calls they make.

vim for example will not write to the file until you issue the ":w" or ":x" commands. It will then detect that the file has changed and makes you confirm the overwriting.

If the program does `open(2)` on the file with the `O_APPEND` flag, before each `write(2)` the file offset is positioned at the end of the file, as if with `lseek(2)`.

So if you have two commands that append like "tee" they will take turns appending.
However, with NFS you still may get corrupted files if more than one process appends data to a file at once, because NFS doesn't support appending to a file and the kernel has to simulate it.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of two or more processes modifying the data of the same file (*inode* in tech lingo) is undefined. The result depends on the particular order the writing processes are scheduled. This is a classic case of a **race condition**, i.e. a result depends on the particular order of process execution.

Comment: Would this simply cause out-of-order text to be appended to the file? Or would it actually cause a situation where both processes ended up writing to a different inodes somehow (even though at first they point to the same file)